# Grouping total sales by weekly

Tags: sql, mariadb

it's I'm a newbie on SQL.
so I want to make a query that makes a trend of sales by weekly.
but when I tried to using this query, somehow the result does not start from Monday to Sunday.
How do I solve this problem?

Thanks

```
select count(sales), week(paymentdate) as weekly
from sales
group by weekly
```

Comment: What's your table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [week()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/week/) and you will find need to set `mode` for it

```
   select count(sales), week(paymentdate,1) as weekly
    from sales
    group by weekly
```